# Choose Audio device for speech recognition

Tags: audio, windows-iot, speech-recognition

I got speech recognition working in a simple UWP app on my Raspberry PI3.

I also wanted to add audio output - with the onboard audio jack the sound was horrible, so I used a USB-Audio adapter. This adapter also has an input (microphone).

The problem - Windows10 now uses this adapter for speech recognition.
Since there is no microphone (mine is on USB) I'm no longer able to use speech recognition.

When I list my devices I find both (USB-Mic - USB-Adapter-Mic).

How can I set this device as "default input"?

Or at least use it with speech recognition (I found a way to choose the output device for media playback - but not for speech recognition).